# Which AssistedInject should I use? Google or Sonatype?

Tags: java, maven, guice, assisted-inject

I am very new to `Guice`, and I need `AssistedInject` in my application. When I looked up the Jar on maven, I saw there were two:

- [org.sonatype.sisu.inject](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.sonatype.sisu.inject|guice-assistedinject|3.1.2|jar)
- [com.google.inject.extensions](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.google.inject.extensions|guice-assistedinject|3.0|jar)

The Sonatype version is more recently updated and has a later version number, but is it actually officially supported by Google and Guice? Or is it's own Nexus thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the Google one unless you find out more about why Sonatype patched Google's version and which versions of other Guice jars you need to use with it.

The Sonatype version 3.2.1 has dependencies on other 3.2.1 Sonatype Guice jars.

There is some info on the Sonatype patches to the Google version of Guice here http://www.sonatype.com/people/2010/01/from-plexus-to-guice-3-creating-a-guice-bean-extension-layer/

It seems they are changing from using Plexus to Guice for their dependency injection and have added some stuff and fixed some stuff they felt was broken. Somewhere else I saw some notes of back fitting their changes (or some of them) to Google's version. I know very little, for sure, about it.